# Trying to install Phusion Passenger gem on debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I tried do

```
gem1.8 install passenger
```

but I get the following error

```
ERROR:  could not find gem passenger locally or in a repository
```

Which I don't understand, cause it clearly is in the repository

```
gem1.8 list -r | grep passenger
```

returns

```
colouringcode-passenger (0.1)
passenger (2.2.9)
passenger-recipes (0.1.2)
passenger_debugger (0.1.3)
```

where do I go from here? I'm stumped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this a couple of hours later and it worked, perhaps it was some intermittent problem with gem

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
sudo gem install passenger
```

Comment: also, I'd be tempted to symlink gem1.8 to gem....  it makes things easier:  sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/local/bin/gem
  - and maybe even do the same for ruby1.8, ri1.8, rdoc1.8 and irb1.8

Answer (score 0):

rm ~/.gem -r

Wasted hours -_-'

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.